# Meaning of LINE: in Perl

Tags: perl, command-line

I was looking at [this Perl one-liner](http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/08/09/commandline.html)

```
perl -n -e 'print "$. - $_"' file
```

and it says that this one liner gets converted to this:

```
LINE:
  while (<>) {
    print "$. - $_"
  }
```

Which is fine, Ijust don't know what `LINE:` is. It doesn't seem like a filehandle, and if it is a variable, it does not have a `$sign` in front of it.

My guess is that it is something like `@F`: an idiom that is just used in Perl one liners. Is `LINE` just something that Perl uses in one-liners from the command line?

Answer (score 7):

It's a label. They provide a way to mark a place in your code. Using labels is not idiomatic as they are rarely needed. Labels can be used with certain commands, namely [`next`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/next.html), [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html), [`redo`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/redo.html) and [`goto`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html).

A label is a bareword followed by a colon, such as `LINE:`

More information can be found in [perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html)